# How can I get the functionality of wordexp(3) when restricted to system calls?

Tags: c, unix, asynchronous, operating-system, system-calls

I'm writing a program that is doing lots of asynchronous signal processing, so I need to restrict myself to system calls in my code. I want the functionality of wordexp(3) but I don't see any alternatives in the man pages. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Comment: What parts of `wordexp()` do you need? It's a very weird function with a lot of strange edge cases. (In particular, it can end up running shell commands under some situations!)

Comment: Why do you think signal processing necessitates using only system calls? Ultimately, all user-space libraries are "only using syscalls" since otherwise they can't have an effect on the rest of the system. (Normally when writing signal handlers, you shouldn't do long blocking operations, but you could easily use the signal handler to quickly add some in-memory information to a queue which is being processed by a different thread which calls `wordexp(3)` itself.)